# Scrapy, crontab does not work because of module not found error

Tags: bash, ubuntu, cron, scrapy, python-3.7

I want to run scrapy with a cron-job. However, I received this error message :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/togayyazar/.local/bin/scrapy", line 6, in <module>
    from scrapy.cmdline import execute
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scrapy'
```

I have manually tried to run scrapy from shell and there was not such this error. It worked properly.

This is my `crontab` file :

```
16 13 * * * export PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin:/home/togayyazar/.local/bin; scrapy shell etsy.com > /var/log/Sc.lg 2>&1
```

Output of `which scrapy` :

```
/home/togayyazar/.local/bin
```

I've also tried this :

```
* * * * * /home/togayyazar/.local/bin/scrapy shell google.com > /var/log/Sc.lg 2>&1
```

and this :

```
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/home/togayyazar/.local/bin
* * * * * /home/togayyazar/.local/bin/scrapy shell google.com > /var/log/Sc.lg 2>&1
```

but none of them worked and I have received the same error. I could not figure out the problem.

Comment: whats the output of `echo $PATH`? copy that output and put it in your crontab

Comment: PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/home/togayyazar/.local/bin is the output of `echo $PATH`. I've put this chunk of code into my crontab and nothing has changed. I still get the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem. These `crontab`s ,I've mentioned, belong to `root`. I put

```
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/home/togayyazar/.local/bin
* * * * * /home/togayyazar/.local/bin/scrapy shell google.com > /var/log/Sc.lg 2>&1
```

into `togayyazar`'s (just an ordinary user of system) crontab and it worked correctly. I guess ,maybe, `root` cannot access `togayyazar`'s `.local` files.